# Is it possible to download stock-data countrywise with quantmod package for R?

Tags: equities, r, finance, quantmod

### Is it possible to download stock-data countrywise with quantmod package for R ?

Hi, I'm wondering if it's possible to download equities countrywise.

Let's say i want all data from the Finnish market.

All Finnish stock symbols ends with .HE, so what I want is

```
getSymbols("all stocks that ends with .HE", ...)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I don't have perfect solution for above problem, I but can help you out with the alternative. As far as my information you can't download the data country wise. I was also looking for the same. You should have all the symbols first in place. I have prepared a small code which loop through the all available symbols and get historical data from Yahoo.

```
library(quantmod)
startDate = "2000-01-01"
thePath = " * "
source(paste(thePath,"code\\listOfInstruments.r",sep=""))

for (ii in theInstruments){
  print(ii)
  data = getSymbols(Symbols = ii, 
                    src = "yahoo", 
                    from = startDate, 
                    auto.assign = FALSE)
  colnames(data) = c("open","high","low","close","volume","adj.")
  write.zoo(data,paste(thePath,ii,".csv",sep=""),sep=",",row.names=FALSE)
}
```

Regarding symbols that you can easily download from exchange and save it, It's a one time job. Rest you can use the above code to get the data life long. I have created database using above code only.

Answer (score 0):

A way is to loop through a list of symbols.

lisym <- c("ELI1V.HE", "KRA1V.HE")
getSymbols(lisym)
ELI1V <- get("ELI1V.HE")
barChart(ELI1V)

or prepare the symbol names in csv file n loop thru it.

lisym <- readLines("stocks.csv")